# MiniMagick tile same image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imagemagick, minimagick

I'm trying to make background by tiling same image (sorry, don't know how to write it correctly, [here's example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqoA0.jpg) ) with `MiniMagick`. I saw `ImageMagick` command `convert -size 1056x576 tile:Castillo_001.gif Castillo_tiled.gif`, but I can't reproduce it in `MiniMagick`. Or maybe here's some better solution, if I already have `MiniMagick::Image` object? Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `Minimagick::Tool::Montage`

```
MiniMagick::Tool::Montage.new do |montage|
  montage.mode 'concatenate'
  11.times do 
    montage << 'yeah.jpg'
  end
  # montage.tile '3x3'
  montage << 'result.jpg'
end
```

You have to add the same same image as many times as you need to have it repeated.

If you specify the `tile`, then you control the `COLxROW` of your result.

If the number of images you send to your montage does not fit in your `tile` specification, different resulting images will be generated. You can check this behavior by uncommenting `montage.tile` in the example provided.

Comment: There are probably better solutions, specifying how to `repeat the same image` instead of `adding the same image multiple times`, maybe a different mode than `concatenate`, handle the column-row grid better and so on... But this answer is a good place to start and it solves your question. Hope it helps.